# Error al intentar iniciar sesion

Tags: php

Cuando trato de iniciar sesión recibo el siguiente error en la consola:

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 'https://2023.proviaje.es/services/generaloperations/adminsession.php?action=verify', ok: false, …}
> error
> :
> error
> :
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "
>  **"... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (https://2023.proviaje.es/vendor.js:26163:51) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://2023.proviaje.es/polyfills.js:621:35) at Object.onInvokeTask (https://2023.proviaje.es/vendor.js:54308:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://2023.proviaje.es/polyfills.js:620:40) at Zone.runTask (https://2023.proviaje.es/polyfills.js:389:51) at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (https://2023.proviaje.es/polyfills.js:702:38) at invokeTask (https://2023.proviaje.es/polyfills.js:1843:18) at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (https://2023.proviaje.es/polyfills.js:1880:25)
> text
> :
> "
> \n**Notice**:  Undefined index: Authorization in **/var/www/vhosts/proviaje.es/2023.proviaje.es/services/generaloperations/adminsession.php** on line 29**
> \n{}"
> [[Prototype]]
> :
> Object
> constructor
> :
> ƒ Object()
> hasOwnProperty
> :
> ƒ hasOwnProperty()
> isPrototypeOf
> :
> ƒ isPrototypeOf()
> propertyIsEnumerable
> :
> ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
> toLocaleString
> :
> ƒ toLocaleString()
> toString
> :
> ƒ ()
> valueOf
> :
> ƒ valueOf()
> **defineGetter**
> :
> ƒ **defineGetter**()
> **defineSetter**
> :
> ƒ **defineSetter**()
> **lookupGetter**
> :
> ƒ **lookupGetter**()
> **lookupSetter**
> :
> ƒ **lookupSetter**()
> **proto**
> :
> (...)
> get **proto**
> :
> ƒ **proto**()
> set **proto**
> :
> ƒ **proto**()
> headers
> :
> HttpHeaders
> lazyInit
> :
> () => {…}
> lazyUpdate
> :
> null
> normalizedNames
> :
> Map(0) {size: 0}
> [[Prototype]]
> :
> Object
> message
> :
> "Http failure during parsing for https://2023.proviaje.es/services/generaloperations/adminsession.php?action=verify"
> name
> :
> "HttpErrorResponse"
> ok
> :
> false
> status
> :
> 200
> statusText
> :
> "OK"
> url
> :
> "https://2023.proviaje.es/services/generaloperations/adminsession.php?action=verify"
> [[Prototype]]
> :
> HttpResponseBase
> defaultErrorLogger  @   core.js:4081
> handleError

Este es mi codigo del archivo afectado:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
    require_once('../get/getadminsession.php');
    require_once('../insert/insertadminsession.php');
    use Firebase\JWT\JWT;



    if (isset ($_GET["action"])){
        $action = $_GET["action"];
        switch ($action) {
            case "get":
                getsession();
                break;
            case "verify":
                verify();
                break;
            }
    }

    function verify (){
        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        $token = $headers['Authorization'];
        $session = null;
        try {
            $session = JWT::decode($token, sessionkey, array('HS256'));
            $adminsession_id = $session->data->adminsession_id;
            $dbsession = getadminsession($adminsession_id);
            if (is_array($dbsession)) {
              $adminsessiondata = $dbsession[0];
              if ( time() > strtotime($adminsessiondata["adminsession_expiration"]) ){
                echo json_encode("expired session");
              }
              else{
                echo json_encode($adminsessiondata["admin_id"]);
              }
            }
            else {
              echo json_encode("no session");
            }
        }
        catch(Firebase\JWT\ExpiredException $exception) {
            echo json_encode("expired session");
        }
        catch(Exception $exception) {
            echo json_encode($exception);
        }
    }

    function createtoken($adminsession_id){
        $resultadminsession = getadminsession($adminsession_id);
        $session = $resultadminsession[0];
        $token = array(
          'exp' => strtotime($session['adminsession_expiration']),
          'data' => [
            'adminsession_id' => intval($session['adminsession_id']),
            'admin_id' => intval($session['admin_id'])
            ]
        );
        $jwt = JWT::encode($token, sessionkey);
        $response = array(true, $jwt);
        echo json_encode($response);

    }

    function getsession(){
        if ( isset($_GET["adminsession_id"]) ){
            $adminsession_id = $_GET["adminsession_id"];
            $result = getadminsession($adminsession_id);
            if (is_array($result)){
                $response = array(true, $result);
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
            else{
                if ($result == "no result"){
                    $response = array(true, $result);
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
                else{
                    $response = array(false, $result);
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
            }
       }
    }

    function insertsession ($admin_id){
        $fields = "adminsession_expiration, admin_id";
        $adminsession_expiration = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+60 minutes", time()));
        $values = "'$adminsession_expiration', $admin_id";
        $result = insertadminsession ($fields, $values);
        if ($result[0] != false){
            createtoken($result[1]);
        }
        else{
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
    }

?>
```

He montado la web en otro servidor y funciona sin problema. Creo que puede ser por las extensiondes de php que esten activadas pero no se cual es la que da el error. Tengo PHP 7.4

Gacias de antemano